Average of multiple normally distributed Datasets
Heyo everyone :)
My math education mostly stopped after school, so please bear with me while I try to describe my issue as best as I can:

In a game I play there's a clear measure for your performance given on any fight ("attempt"), and said performance is influenced by the inherent randomness of the game and the actor you play to a degree. You can simulate the performance of any given actor across hundreds of thousands of attempts to pretty much any degree of precision you'd like, receiving a dataset of the performance of each of these simulated attempts in turn. This is used to grasp the average and median performance, standard deviation etc.
For any of the actors in the game, this performance dataset turns out to be normally distributed according to an online Shapiro-Wilk test.
There exists an actor though, whose performance on any given try solely relies on the average of the performance of 4 other actors during that try. His performance on any try is basically $Performance = (PerfA + PerfB + PerfC + PerfD)/4$
I'd like to know stuff like the standard deviation of this actors performance, how likely he is to perform within the top 10% of his potential, etc.

As you can easily get the datasets of any actors performance, I could probably just write a program that multiplies all the different possible combinations of performance that could occur with 4 given actors and then calculate the results. Do this for every possible combination of 4 different actors in the game, and check if there's maybe a pattern I can observe.
But that's a loooot of effort and time, and I'd hope that there maybe is some more generalised approach you can take given that the individual datasets are all normally distributed.
